# Unit testing in Django / Tastypie

Tags: django, unit-testing, tastypie

I am trying to run a few tests for my tastypie app but i get the following error.

```
Finding files... done.
Importing test modules ... Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev_4.4.0.201510052309\pysrc\pydev_runfiles.py", line 468, in __get_module_from_str
    mod = __import__(modname)
  File "DjangoTastypie/myApp\tests.py", line 2, in <module>
    from tastypie.test import ResourceTestCaseMixin
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tastypie\test.py", line 9, in <module>
    from tastypie.serializers import Serializer
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tastypie\serializers.py", line 12, in <module>
    from tastypie.exceptions import BadRequest, UnsupportedFormat
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tastypie\exceptions.py", line 83, in <module>
    class ImmediateHttpResponse(TastypieError):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tastypie\exceptions.py", line 94, in ImmediateHttpResponse
    _response = HttpResponse("Nothing provided.")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\http\response.py", line 340, in __init__
    super(HttpResponse, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\http\response.py", line 125, in __init__
    content_type = '%s; charset=%s' % (settings.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named DjangoTastypie.settings
ERROR: Module: tests could not be imported (file: DjangoTastypie\myApp\tests.py).
done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev_4.4.0.201510052309\pysrc\runfiles.py", line 234, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\use\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev_4.4.0.201510052309\pysrc\runfiles.py", line 78, in main
    return pydev_runfiles.main(configuration)  # Note: still doesn't return a proper value.
  File "C:\Users\user\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev_4.4.0.201510052309\pysrc\pydev_runfiles.py", line 835, in main
    PydevTestRunner(configuration).run_tests()
  File "C:\Users\user\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev_4.4.0.201510052309\pysrc\pydev_runfiles.py", line 793, in run_tests
    MyDjangoTestSuiteRunner(run_tests).run_tests([])
  File "C:\Users\user\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev_4.4.0.201510052309\pysrc\pydev_runfiles.py", line 813, in run_tests
    raise AssertionError("Unable to run suite with DjangoTestSuiteRunner because it couldn't be imported.")
AssertionError: Unable to run suite with DjangoTestSuiteRunner because it couldn't be imported.
```

Do I need to add somthing to the installed_apps section of the settings.py ? Or do my tests need to be located elsewhere ? Right now I am using the basic structure that you get when you start a new Django project and my test is on tests.py

OK so I found out that the issue was with Eclipse -> Run as pyunit option. Now when I run it using manage.py test I get this error

```
======================================================================
ERROR: myApp.tests (unittest.loader.ModuleImportFailure)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: myApp.tests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\unittest\loader.py", line 254, in _find_tests
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\unittest\loader.py", line 232, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\dhanushka.amarakoon\git\lcapi\DjangoTastypie\myApp\tests.py", line 2, in <module>
    from tastypie.test import ResourceTestCaseMixin
ImportError: cannot import name ResourceTestCaseMixin
```

Comment: can you provide the `tests.py` file?

Comment: Which version of Django? What command are you using to run your tests? Also, show us your manage.py file.

Comment: I think the error was due to the fact that I was running the tests using eclipses run as pyunit option.

Answer (score 0):

OK i figured out what I did wrong. First I was using eclipse->run and pyunit which was using a older code. And then I got the import error coz I used the wrong class name ResourceTestCaseMixin instead of ResourceTestCase